# Display object on video in Unity

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, camera, display

I am developing an AR application with Unity & OpenCV for Unity.

As it detects an object with the Android camera and at specific key point, it has to display something(for example, just a dot) on that position of the key point(so I know where the key point is in pixel coordinate.)

As it is a real-time camera, the position will be continuously changed since the camera will move too.

As I am a newbie in this field, I'm not sure as it is possible.

```
  VideoCapture video(0);    // open the default camera
  Image frame = new Image();
  Mat capture;
  //variables for drawing
  var color = new Bgr(this.color.GreenColor);
  int radius;
  int lineType = 8;

  //now for each frame
  WHILE(1)
      bool capture_valid = true;
      TRY
         video >> capture;  // save each frame into capture.
      CATCH
         capture_vaild = false;
      ENDTRYCATCH
      IF (capture_vaild)
         frame.setMatImage(capture);    // save capture into frame

         //draw circle on video
         CvInvoke.cvCircle(frame, center, radius, color.MCvScalar, -1, lineType, 0);
     ENDIF
  ENDWHILE
```

I'm not sure if it works, since the capturing image will be updated for each frame. Or is there another way that I can display an object directly to the real-time camera?